# Will the meaning/nuance change in the following construction?

Tags: meaning, grammar, comparative-constructions

I was going through some sentences and I found that the word かぜ was used before 私は and in one after 私は.
E.g.

> 私はなぜ風邪をひいているの
>
> なぜ私は風邪をひいているの

So, my question is; Is there a difference between the two?

Moreover, what about いつでも in the same case:

> 私はいつでも風邪をひいているの
>
> いつでも私は風邪をひいているの

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both mean the same thing, but the second form occurs less frequently and attracts attention. So, normally you'd use the first form, but for the impact you might go for the second form.

E.g. let's say my boss is asking:

> (1) 昨日の書類なぜここに置いてあるの？
>   (2) なぜ昨日の書類ここに置いてあるの？

The second form sounds definitely more alarming than the former (it's hard to say it in a way that doesn't convey irritation).

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatically same in meaning. Except by pronunciation focus can be shifted to 私 or 風邪. English translation for both is same "Why do I have cold", here the focus is shifted just by pronunciation.